# How to fix BSOD caused by hal.dll, ntoskrnl.exe, PSHED.dll?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, crash

So I have been struggling with this issue for several months now, trying to understand what causes my PC to repeatedly get BSOD on error WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR.
I did mostly everything I could do in order to fix it but with no success yet. There might be improvements in how frequent it comes, but it's still there.

I will get into details:

PC parts:
CPU - i7-7820X CPU @ 3.60GHz
MBoard - x299 AORUS Gaming 3 Pro-CF
Memory - G.Skill Sumsong 2133 2x8
GPU - Nvidia Geforce 970 GIGABYTE

Dump file [here](https://pastebin.com/g22dgfAy).

It seems that the BSOD mostly happens when I'm working on my PC. Can happens in-game or even when just browsing, or working on some text file. The last two crashes were when I opened a video/screenshot on Whatsapp web.
It feels like it's related to drivers but I just can't tell.
about two months ago, I was playing WoW classic while talking with a friend on Discord (with Voice), and I would estimate my PC was crashing about 6-7 times in two hours.
After I closed Discord, it stopped for a while.

So the first thing I did was to format C:\ but this didn't help. It kept crashing with the same errors.Not every crash was involved in a BSOD. Sometimes it just restarts the PC with no error.
I cleaned it properly from dust and parts temperature were OK.
I took my PC to a Computer Lab where I bought it. They claimed there was an error with the Memory slots so they replaced it (warranty).
I took the PC home and guess what, It kept falling like nothing happened, leaving me in big frustration.
After a few days I took the PC again to that Computer Lab. The PC was about a week over there, and they just couldn't simulate the problem I described, They said all my PC parts are OK,
and that's it I just went up there, took my computer and went home. They couldn't simulate a BSOD.
They recommended to replace Power supply so I replaced it but it didn't help... BSOD was still showing up.
They said it could be something plug that causing it so I removed all unnecessary USB's but that didn't help either.
I installed Windows 10 again on my secondary Hard drive and that didn't help as well.
I downloaded the Intel Driver & Support Assistance, and updated all drivers.
For two weeks everything seemed to be fine until it randomly crashed on Whatsapp web while I started to watch a video.

PC age is about two years except GPU which is about 5 years old (GTX 970).

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: HAL.dll is intended for hardware abstraction layer, which helps the kernel to run on variety of hardware. And ntoskrnl.exe is actually the NT kernel  which is very critical to boot and run the system. Then you might have got a serious problem, and good idea is to reinstall windows on your computer.

Comment: ^ This, or a failing hard drive.

Comment: Debug the windows dump file is the only way.